# How to share a counter between multiple Android applications

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm working on a library which will be used by multiple applications, potentially concurrently.

The library needs to keep track of a counter that will be shared between applications.

Every time an application performs a specific action I want to increment the shared counter.

I'm aware of Shared Content Providers, but since they don't provide thread-safe operations on their own I'm not sure if they are a feasible option.

Everything I'm finding about making them thread-safe seems to only apply to making concurrent calls from within the same application.

Is it possible to use shared content providers cross application and still ensure thread safety?

If not what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: "thread safety" doesn't make sense in the context of two /different/ processes/applications. Did you consider using some XPC tool (pipes, shared memory) or simply a file?

Comment: For my library I unfortunately need to carry over the counter even between reboots of the device, so I think that will rule out pipes and shared memory. I considered a file but was hoping there would be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Files are there for exactly this purpose.